# Add the same image with different offsets to the accumulating image on GPU

Tags: image-processing, gpu, gpgpu

As the title states, I am trying to add the same image with different offsets, stored in a list, to the accumulating image.

[image]
The current implementation performs this on a CPU, and with some intrinsics it can be quite fast.

However, with larger images (2048x2048) and many offsets in the list (~10000), the performance is not satisfactory.

My question is, can the accumulation of the image with different offsets be efficiently implemented on a GPU?

Comment: The short answer is yes it can. On a GPU the summation for different target pixels can be performed in parallel (of course not all of the 4 million, but a lot more than on a CPU). The exact way of course depends on wether you choose cuda, opencl, opengl or whatever. It can be done with all of them. If precision is key in your application, be aware that double precision is by far slower than single precision on a mainstream gpu. If you use single precision, you also might want to use a Kahan summation algorithm for each pixel to minimize, especially if your data has a high dynamic range.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  The results will be likely *much* faster than on CPU.  The trick is to not send the data for each addition, and to not even launch a new kernel for each addition: the kernel you have should do some decent number of offset additions at once, at least 16 but possibly a few hundred, depending on your typical list size (and you can have more than one kernel of course).